# Complex query of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have looked up the manual of MongoDB, but cannot find a proper solution to do the following search:

Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57201082e92c07baef62452a"),
    "user_id" : 1,
    "profile" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-10-11T12:58:06.000Z"),
            "content" : [ 
                {
                    "feature_id" : 1,
                    "feature_value" : true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-04-12T8:23:09.000Z"),
            "content" : [ 
                {
                    "feature_id" : 1,
                    "feature_value" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to get is the **LATEST** `feature_value` of a given `user_id` and a given `feature_id`.

Is there any way to accomplish this using MongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the last element in the "profile" array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the latest(as profile.date) you can use the following to get the desired result.(query not tested, hope it works).

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
  {$match : {"user_id" : 1}},
  {$unwind : "$profile"},
  {$unwind : "$profile.content"},
  {$match : {"profile.content.feature_id" : 1}},
  {$sort : {"profile.date" : -1}},
  {$limit : 1},
  {$group:{_id : "$_id", content : {$push:"$profile.content"}}}
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
{$match:{"user_id" :1,"profile.content.feature_id":1}},
{$project:{"profile.content.feature_value":1}},
{$sort:{"profile.date" :-1}},
{$limit : 1});
```